# Structure not properly extending in Discord.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

Why is message.guild.settings undefined with this code? Using discord.js@dev and TypeScript

```
class CustomGuild extends Structures.get('Guild') {
    constructor(client, data) {
        super(client, data);
    }

    get settings(): any {
        return guildData.findOne({
            id: this.id
        }).get('settings') || defaultConfig;
    }
}

Structures.extend('Guild', () => CustomGuild);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you require this file from the main file? or is this in the main file?

Comment: This is in the main file.

Comment: well, its been almost a month  lol, anyway just saying: discord.js v13 removes structures so u shouldnt bother with structures, since u will have to change them when v13 release and u changed to it

Comment: so as u say ur using @dev, if its the latest version, yeee u cant use structures

Comment: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/6027 <<< related pr (its merged)